# Facebook Javascript SDK - Score post requires application secret key

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using facebook score api with javascript SDK. I need to post score of logged in fb user to facebook for my application. The code i have require both application id and 
application secret key in Javascript. It is not taking the access token of user and giving oAuth error. Puttng secret key in JS is not a good practice and i need to
have a solution where FB offers something to avoid such loop holes.

I am using following code where data_box contains application id, secreted key and score.

```
    FB.api("/"+FB.getUserID()+"/scores", 'post', data_box, function(responsedata){
          FB.api("/"+data_box.app_id+"/scores", 'get', {}, responsefunction);
    });
```

Can any one please help me to update code so that instead of application secret key, it use user acccess token to submit the score.

Thanks in advance,

Jacob